# Module uninstallation does not remove configuration

Tags: magento2, module

I have my own module installed via composer and I can uninstall it with

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall XXX_XXX
```

But when I reinstall the module the configuration (values in system.xml) is still the same as it was setup while it was installed before. Do I have to remove the configurations manually? How?

EDIT:
My current Uninstall class:

```
<?php

namespace XXXX\XXXXX\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

    class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
    {
        public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->dropTable($connection->getTableName('mytable_data'));

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `uninstall`-command actually only removes anything when you invoke it with `--remove-data` and your module has an `Uninstall` class that implements `Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface`. I believe if you want to remove configuration values, you can also do this here.

The official documentation is a place to start: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

**EDIT**

As far as I can see, the `Uninstall` class does not have access to the configuration by default, so you should define an own constructor to fix this. Code is shortened and untested:

```
<?php

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface
     */
    protected $resourceConfig;

    public function __construct(  
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface $resourceConfig
    ) {
        $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, in your `uninstall()`-function, use that interface's `deleteConfig()` method to delete your configuration:

```
$this->resourceConfig->deleteConfig(
    'my/config_path',
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 
    \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
);
```

Comment: I have an Uninstall Class in my module and the commands in there are getting called when uninstalling. But I am not doing anything manually with the configuration in there. Does that mean I have to remove the normal configuration data by hand in the Uninstall file? How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I don't have any code that deletes the configuration. That is what I need.

Comment: Can you please share your uninstall class?

Comment: Sure. I edited my post above.